# Does C++ have a unit type?

Tags: c++, unit-type

I know that the C++ standard library has a unit type - I've seen it before - but I can't remember what it's called.  It starts with an "m", I know that much, and it is equivalent to this definition:

```
struct Unit {};
```

Basically, a unit type is a type with only one distinct value - as contrasted with `void` which has zero values and `bool` which has two.

---

If you must know, my particular use case was regarding the constructors of a template class with a union member.  It pretty much looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
    union {
        T t;
        std::string str;
    } data;
    foo(T const& t) {
        data.t = t;
    }
    foo(std::monostate unused, std::string const& str) {
        data.str = str;
    }
};
```

In order to be able to distinguish the two constructors from one another, should `T` be equal to `std::string`, a sentry argument in the second constructor is needed.  `void` won't work of course, and `bool` wouldn't make sense because there would be no difference between passing in `true` vs `false` - what was needed was a unit type.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking - post some code that illustrates what you want.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I did.

Comment: OP's talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). In Scala, there's a type called `Unit` that's used in generic programming in cases when a function is parameterized to return nothing. You can't parameterize with `void` because then the function result can't be assigned, so you substitute with an empty class, the `Unit` class. Similar concepts exist in other functional languages. OP's asking if there's anything in C++ like this, and they're right. It is `std::monostate`

Comment: Bizarre that the answer is in the original question!

Comment: @user2023370 If you check the history, it isn't; the author found the answer himself and edited the question after.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called [`std::monostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) (Since C++17). It also overloads the `==` operator to return true, as well as some other operators, so that all instances of `std::monostate` are equal.

Answer (score 7):

C++ has arbitrarily many unit types, including

- [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t)
- [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate)
- [`std::tuple<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)
- `struct unit {};`